# Borderlands 2 Multiple of same DLCs?

Tags: technical-issues, borderlands-2

When I bought Borderlands 2 on Steam, I bought just the standard edition. I little later on I purchased the season pass, and everything was totally fine.

During the summer sale, I bought the rest of the DLC that the season pass didn't get me. I went to try to load my character and the game gets stuck on the loading screen forever. Literally forever. It never stops. The only thing that has changes is the new DLC.

When i right clicked and checked the DLC that I had for the game, I had multiples of some of them.

- I have "Collector's Edition" and "Collector's Edition Pack", which I assume are the same thing.
- I have "Creature Dome" and "Creature Slaughterdome", which also must be the same thing.
- And I have 2 Ultimate vault Hunter Upgrades.

I tried disabling all DLC, reinstalling the game, and verifying the game cache.

When I verify the game cache it says one file failed to validate and will be reacquired. But is doesn't seem to reacquire it since it says this every time.

Any ideas how I could have multiple of the same DLCs? And what is wrong with the game?

Comment: Have you tried a complete removal of the game?  Save your character files just in case.  Do a google search to fine them.

Comment: A Google search to fine them? I have uninstalled and re installed it.

Comment: Your profile files.  I didn't feel like actually looking in order to tell you specifically.

Comment: Have you saved your character ? I would try in that order : Go in your steam library > right click BL2 > delete local content > restart steam > reinstall BL2 > retry. I've never heard of such a glitch so if that doesznt work you might want to try your luck with  [the steam support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1231-UIBN-0311)

Comment: Can you specify which dlc are making your game get broken ?

Answer (score -1):

I had a very similar issue with the first borderlands along with quite a few other people. There are a few things that you can try but the main issue comes with the way that gearbox looks at dlc activation.

The old solution is to disable Windows Firewall, UAC, and add Everyone (Full Control) to the C: Drive under security.

This should allow for gearbox to activate your dlc properly.

If this doesnt work with all the dlc activated then chances are that your save data could be currupted. (this i am guessing would be very bad, I hope you have a backup.) In this case you may need to delete and reinstall and start from scratch.

Also just to check that your save isnt currupt, disable the dlc and try the 3 steps listed above.

Comment: I *really* recommend against the "add Everyone (Full Control) to the C: Drive under security" option. It completely cancels every bit of security your system had, since now anything running at any privilege level can overwrite system files.

Comment: This isnt as much of an issue as it may seem. one i presume you are using a personal computer so not many accounts, secondly you can go back after the initial launch and reset your accounts to their normal privaleges. it is only for the first time you run the dlc so the game can properly activate your content.

Comment: If you're going to do this at least only do it for the Steam directory, or even better the Borderland 2 directory.